# How to reduce size of trainer file trained by open cv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working with a huge dataset and when I trainned them using opencv , My trained file's size is too big . How can I simply reduce my trained file size?

Comment: could you post the code you used for training

Comment: https://ideone.com/Bncq2H